# Optimizing this SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, optimization

How would you optimize the following query?

- 'example_companies' contains companies data.
- 'example_roles_companies' contains companies roles (pivot)
- 'example_industries_companies' contains companies industries (pivot)

---

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.id,
                a.mode,
                a.name,
                a.city,
                b.name AS USER,
                b.phone
FROM   example_companies a
       LEFT JOIN example_users b
         ON a.contact_id = b.id
       LEFT JOIN example_roles_companies c
         ON a.id = c.company_id
WHERE  "2" IN (SELECT industry_id
               FROM   example_industries_companies
               WHERE  company_id = a.id)
       AND c.role_id = 2
       AND a.account_mode != 2
ORDER  BY a.id
```

Comment: No. The query works but I'm just wondering if there is some ways to optimize it.

Comment: If it is slow then you should think about adding some indexes.

Comment: What you want to optimize? Execution speed? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What's wrong with the question? The query is not slow but I'm looking for tips to make it faster without adding indexes.

Comment: @Jacob: Execution speed.

Comment: @user366292 then we need the structure of the table(SHOW CREATE TABLE). Read this- http://www.techrepublic.com/article/three-easy-ways-to-optimize-your-mysql-queries/6137168

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.id,
                a.mode,
                a.name,
                a.city,
                b.name AS USER,
                b.phone
FROM example_companies a
LEFT JOIN example_users b ON a.contact_id = b.id
INNER JOIN example_roles_companies c ON a.id = c.company_id AND c.role_id = 2
INNER JOIN example_industries_companies i
        ON i.company_id = a.id AND i.industry_id = "2"
WHERE 
    a.account_mode != 2
ORDER BY 
    a.id
```

Structure:

- Index on a.id, not null
- Index on b.id, not null [analyze the opportunity of adding another index (b.id, b.name, b.phone) to this table as well]
- Index on (c.company_id, c.role_id) not null both
- Index on (i.company_id, i.industry_id), not null both

Remarks:

Please note that your `industry_id = "2"` seems weird to me, ids are generally numbers and if they are not then it should be looked since integers are faster to process than strings. Additionally, this way of double-quoting is not usual in mysql. Are you sure of your syntax?